# s3:ObjectCreated:* lambda trigger does not work for files written in directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I got a lambda function that should get triggered every time a new objet is uploaded to a specified S3 bucket.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "my_notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id
  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.mylambda.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }
}
```

The lambda function get triggered and executes as expected whenever I upload an object in the root directory `/` of the bucket. However for object created in nested directories e.g in `AWSLogs/` or `AWSLogs/subfolder` or `AWSLogs/subfolder/subfolder` ... the trigger is not working.

I cannot understand why, I am using no `prefix`. This as far as I understand should match all the objects in the bucket, regardless if they are inside a directory or not.

Comment: The lambda is probably invoked but throws an error or something like that. You could try subscribing a queue first, at least for testing purposes, that way you know for sure what messages are sent out.

Comment: Are you sure the Lambda function isn't being triggered at all? Could it be that it is triggering but the function is throwing an error?

Comment: You are right guys, the function does get triggered. Thank you.